# Pre or Post Incrementing React state with ++ throws read only error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, operators

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App(){
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const onIncrement = () => {
      setCounter(++counter)
  };

  return(
      <div>
          <h1>{counter}</h1>
          <button onClick={onIncrement}>Increment</button>
      </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

In the above snippet, onClick of Increment button (++counter) throws **Uncaught TypeError: "counter" is read-only**

Whereas, if I change this to counter+1, this works fine. I understand counter+1 and ++counter are the same with respect to output but technically, internally they're different. How are they different? I saw a blog where a C programmer explains about ++ operator using register and referring to the same address location unlike other math operations. Why is this increment attempt caught as error in React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ReactJS, the count variable is immutable, read-only, and when you use the ++ increment you are trying to directly change the count variable

when you use the setCounter () function by passing count + 1, you are passing a value, without changing the original value of the variable. Under the hood, setCounter makes a copy of the count with this updated value, maintaining immutability

Comment: I understand setState is asynchronous and does not modify the original state, the whole idea of shadow DOM revolves around this Immutability. But when I do setCounter(count+1) I'm incrementing count by 1, if setCounter can make a copy of count under the hood for +1 then why not for ++ ?

Comment: @deechris27 i will modify my answer to make you understand better.

Comment: because ++ you are changing the value directly in counter, when you use +1, you are passing a value so that the setCouter function performs the operation

Answer (score 1):

++ Operator tries to alter the variable itself, and at a theoretical level counter being readonly React state naturally  should throw an error. Curiously enough this error is avoided by using a "let" initializer with your state; therefore the error is encountered by trying to alter the value of a constant. Although following functional operations (with no side effects) one should make the change in a more safely manner. One simple way to do this might be:

```
const onIncrement = () => {
    setCounter(counter+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
++counter
```

is equivalent to:

```
counter = counter + 1;
```

so:

```
setCounter(++counter)
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
setCounter(counter = counter + 1)
```

but since counter is `const` you get: **Uncaught TypeError: "counter" is read-only**