# React Native : make useState update on real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have this code on react native where I increment a counter by 1 after each button press

```
     function App() {
          const [counter,setCounter]=useState(0);
          return (
            <View>
              <Button title="hello" onPress={()=> 
              {setCounter(counter+1);console.log("display 
               counter in console" ,counter)}}>
                </Button>

              {counter%2==1 ? <Text> display counter in UI</Text> 
               : null }
    
               <View>
               <Text> thank you for clicking the button </Text>
               </View>
        
            </View>
           )
             }
```

After the first click the counter is equal to 0 and the console shows 0 instead of 1 so the JSX component won't show.
I know that useState is asynchronous but how to solve it if showing a JSX is depending  on updating the state on real time.

**UPDATE: It seems that the JSX displays when excpected but I'm wondering why console.log will not update on real time ? I mean why console.log shows 0 when it is supposed to show 1**

Comment: What do you need synchronous updates for? Your component should rerender with the new state as soon as you click the button, however the console.log call will not because it is called in the previous render.

Comment: @Altareos why console.log will not update on real time ? I mean why console.log shows 0 if the real value is 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add pre-increment operator on `setCounter` state. and Change const to var in useState declaration.

https://snack.expo.dev/j70TThHHb

```
export default function App() {
              var [counter,setCounter]=useState(0);
              return (
                <View style={{marginTop:25}}>
                  <Button title="hello" onPress={()=> 
                  {setCounter(++counter);
                  console.log("display  counter in console" ,counter)}}>
                    </Button>
    
                  {counter%2==1 ? <Text> display counter in UI</Text> 
                   : null }
        
                   <View>
                   <Text> thank you for clicking the button </Text>
                   </View>
            
                </View>
               )
                 }
```

Comment: thank you it works , but can you explain why I should change const to var and why I put ++ on the left please

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65483230/9158543.

Comment: For pre-increment and post-increment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

Comment: and why change const  to var if we are using setCounter(++counter) not counter = ++counter

Answer (score 1):

`useState` hook is asynchronous, so you can not access it's new values immediately
And there is no callback for it (unlike `setState`)
But if you want to listen to it's changes, you can use `useEffect` hook like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('display  counter in console', counter);
}, [counter]);
```

Comment: I understand that it is asynchronous but actually the state changed to 1 on first click but the console displays 0 so why it is only asynchrounous for the console ?

Comment: @coldprogrammmer because asynchronous functions does not completely executes immediately after calling them. It means your `console.log` executes before `setCounter` finishes completely